# VS Code explorer color file only not directory unless folded?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to only color files that have had their git statuses changed and not all parent folders, unless the directory the modified file is in is folded (and color only that folder and not all parents)?

Currently if a file has changed with respect to version control, every folder in the path is also colored, leading to too much color info for my liking:

[image: git file color]

I'd like everything except for the file `someService.ts` to be the same color as the `models` directory.

Also, if possible, all the info on the right (green dots and U) isn't really necessary anymore since the coloring conveys that information, so it's clutter for me. Would it be possible to remove that information and only display the number of errors/warnings in the file?

Answer (score 1):

I have found no built in settings that allows you to set the colors of folders/files individually.  It's either all or nothing.  To turn the colors on and off, toggle the `explorer.decorations.colors` setting:

[image: color setting]

There is a settings to remove the green dots/letters.  These are called "badges." To turn them off, toggle the `explorer.decorations.badges` setting:

[image: Badges settings]

This will however also remove the same badges that display the number of errors in a file, etc.

Comment: Thanks, is this something that's configurable with a custom extension? I might be interested in looking into how to implement this functionality if its even possible.

Comment: @IsaacTorres I don't know if there are any plugins that extend this functionality.  Briefly searching, I don't think so.